# Determine if point already shown on google earth

Tags: kml, google-earth

I have a large dataset of points and to stop from showing them all at the same time i'm using nested regions. These regions have network links in them to a server which generates kml files of points and more network links. I'll show x points at the outermost region. That region is made up of smaller regions each showing x points etc. I don't want to show each point more than once. Each point is eligible under many different regions. How can i determine if i've already shown a point?

Ideas:

- Use a deterministic algorithm to pick out the points for a level so each region can reverse calculate what points would already have been selected. Problem is that as soon as a point gets added to the database, the algorithm is no longer going to work as the parameters have changed. Also sounds sloooow.
- store in the db upon population what region a point should be shown at based on some algorithm. Problem is have to decide where to put a point every time you add one. (not that bad initially assign regions for all points though)

Edit: Or instead of using accumulative regions i could set the maximum LOD for each region.
Con is lots of points could be loaded multiple times. Pro, should be pretty simple / updating DB when already in google earth won't hurt things

Edit Edit: Tried using exclusive regions (https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/images/LodRange3.gif) Ran into some problems.  Namely, if you set there is slight overlap where one region ends (max LOD) and another starts (min LOD) could make it so there's a gap, but it will never be perfect. Also this is okay if you start fully zoomed out so the outermost region is 'active', then as you zoom in somewhere the regions will become active. Problem is if you start zoomed in, then your your outer region is never loaded, so it never loads any of it's subregions and the placemarks won't be displayed. Generating all the possible regions from the start (just not displaying them) is not an option as there would be millions of files